# Are the webapp integration useless?

Tags: unity, webapps, facebook, hud

Ubuntu asks for installing various websites' webapp versions by prompting when I open the particular website. As of now, I've installed WordPress, Facebook Messenger, and Reddit. But I don't see any use of them.

I read [a post on Canonical](http://blog.canonical.com/2012/07/19/introducing-ubuntu-web-apps-setting-the-web-free-of-the-browser/) regarding this, and it seemed pretty cool. Notify OSD, native HUD and other generic Ubuntu-specific frameworks are promised to be fully exploited with these integrations, but in practice, it seems just talk and no action.

For example, when I search Facebook in Dash, and click on the webapp Facebook Messenger, it just kicks the browser and opens a new window with facebook.com (even if another window is already open).

All that seems to be working is some FM website that is of no use for me.

I want to know what are benefits of these webapps integration and how do I use the webapps I've installed (let's say the Facebook one).

Answer (score 2):

Other than just creating shortcut in launcher you won't get any feature that you would not get in regular browser.

I did once, the native browser does not give you many features like bookmark, add-ons etc. It will just create a shortcut in dash that you can search and just launch without typing URL

Comment: There's no native advantage? The post says that it will decrease dependency on the browser and also, the prompt reads "Would you like to install xyz for more features?" Surely Ubuntu can't be selling crap with the blog post and prompt messages and wasting its resources over nothing but Dash-embedded bookmarks.

Comment: @Abhimanyu there is no big deal about this Ubuntu feature, just try it out. I did once, the native browser does not give you many features like bookmark, add-ons etc. It will just create a shortcut in dash that you can search and just launch without typing URL